# Bounding the Betti numbers of Čech complexes in Euclidean space

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, extremal-combinatorics

Let $S$ be a set of $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$, where $d \ge 2$. Then let $C=C(S)$ denote the union of closed balls of radius $1$ centered at points of $S$.

For $0 \le j \le d-1$, how large can the Betti number $b_j ( C)$ be? Let $M=M(n,j,d)$ be the maximum possible Betti number over all configurations of $n$ points. We're mostly interested in the asymptotic rate of growth of $M$ as $j$ and $d$ are fixed and $n \to \infty$. By the Nerve Theorem, the union of balls $C$ is homotopy equivalent to the [Čech complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8Cech_complex), so you can consider the Čech complex instead of the union of balls if you like.

In all the examples we know of, we have that $M(n,j,d) \le c n$. Here $c=c(j,d)$ is a constant that depends on $j$ and $d$, but not on $n$. Does this hold in general?

Here are a few things we know.

1. A linear bound certainly holds for $j=0$.
2. If you consider the Vietoris–Rips complex instead of the Čech complex, it holds for $j=1$ and $d\ge 2$, but fails for larger $j,d$. In particular, according to [this paper of Goff](https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.0040), once $j=2$ and $d=5$, the Betti number can be of order at least $n^{3/2}$.
3. A linear upper bound on Betti numbers holds asymptotically almost surely for random Čech and Vietoris–Rips complexes (in any regime of parameter). A proof for the Vietoris–Rips setting can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.1649).

But at the moment we don't even know if a linear bound on the Betti numbers of the Čech complex holds in the special case when $j=1$ and $d=2$.